# Is it possible to calculate the average in one query with Eloquent with two hasMany Relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My current approach looks like this:

```
public function overallAverage() 
{
    $ids = $this->reviews()->pluck('id')->all();

    return Rating::where('rating_type_id', 0)
                  ->whereIn('offer_review_id', $ids)
                  ->avg('rating_value');
}
```

But I don't like it that I first need to pluck all ids in order to calculate the averages. To understand it better here is a diagram of my tables:

[image]

So when I have an Offer, I want to calculate all the averages of ratings that have the rating_type_id of 0.

1 Offer has many Offer Reviews. One Offer Review has many Ratings (like overall, taste rating, value rating etc).

With reviews() I get the has Many relationship

```
public function reviews(){
    return $this->hasMany(OfferReview::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get average of values by using laravel collection. Laravel provide us number of collection helper functions that provide us flexibility to calculate values.

Below is the `avg` collect helper function uses

`https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-average`

```
public function overallAverage() 
{
    $reviewTableName = $this->reviews()->getTable();

    $query = "select id from $reviewTableName";
    $avg = Rating::where('rating_type_id', 0)
                ->whereRaw("offer_review_id in ($query)")
                ->pluck('rating_value')
                ->avg();
    return $avg;
}
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: It's actually similar to my approach, but I wanted to know if it is possible to do this in one query. I just don't like it to make one query to get all the ids and then another query to find the avarages...

Comment: Just to learn a bit more, do you think those two approaches make a difference in scalability? is the second approach faster?